# Is there any available Facebook widget for "Places"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I am trying to embed a widget for a 3rd party Facebook "Place". 
It seems that widgets only work for "Pages" or "Profiles", but not Places.
The place is being actively managed,  it has posts from its owner (it's a hotel), so it's not one of those "automatically" created places.
All widget results for the place come up empty. If I try a Page or Profile, they work normally. So it's not code-related, it has something to do with the Facebook's categorization as "Place".

Are there any widgets that can be used for Facebook "places"? I'm more interested in the "page" widget: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

The place i'm referring to (not that it matters): [link](https://www.facebook.com/AVRA-Hotel-Rafina-281292128597265/). Notice how there are recent active "page-like" posts.

Comment: Places are pages. But the page in question is access-restricted somehow (age, location, ...), and the Page Plugin only works for fully public pages with no restrictions whatsoever.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that. Is there something I can check against in order to verify that the page is public? I am working on a business-directory site, and I don't know beforehand what kind of fb page each business has. Also, care to post your comment as an answer in order to upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Places are pages.

But the page in question is access-restricted somehow (age, location, ...), and the Page Plugin only works for fully public pages with no restrictions whatsoever.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#privacy

> Is there something I can check against in order to verify that the page is public?

You mean in an automated way? Well, if you have the page id or page username, you can use those to make an API request - using your app access token. For pages that are restricted in any way, that will return an "Unsupported GET Request" error message.